# Update Data Extension in Contact Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contactbuilder, entry-criteria

I would like to know if the use case I am trying to build is feasible. In Journey Builder I have a Standard Data Extension as Entry Source that contains all the data needed to be used in the journey.

I have some decision splits that will check if the value of the field of that Data Extension has changed or not (e.g. FieldA = True). For that, I am thinking on linking the Data Extension in Contact Builder in order to use the most updated data in the Decision Split based on Contact Data (the data extension will be updated with a query in a daily basis). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and you don't necessarily have to link them together in Data Designer.

You can have one data extensions used as an entry source for your journey, and a second one that stores the "updated" data, and both of them set up as two different attribute groups.

As long as you have the same SubscriberKey in both of them, and it's related to the Contact Key in your contact model, it will work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Just to double-check. As long as the entry source Data Extension will be updated on a daily basis to inject new customers, it should be enough to add it in Data Designer, right? I don't need another Data Extension.

Comment: Yes, that would work as well